# Is there an elegant regex to grep a MAC address accounting for various delimiters?

Tags: shell, grep

I will occasionally search aggregate logs files on my syslog server for a specific MAC address. Since each source uses a different format for MAC addresses, I usually use this command:

```
less syslog.log | grep -i -E '56[:-\.]?ea[:-\.]?b6[:-\.]?a6[:-\.]?82[:-\.]?5e'
```

Which will find the address regardless of the format or case (`56eab6a6825e`, `56ea.b6a6.825e`, `56:ea:b6:a6:82:5e`, `56-EA-B6-A6-82-5E`).

I have this command saved in text file so I can just replace each hex pair with the relevant digits and paste it in, but is there an elegant way format my regex where I can have the whole address together? For example:

```
less syslog.log | grep -i -E '56eab6a6825e[:-\.]?(anywhereinthestring)'
```

I basically want to be more lazy when searching, but I don't understand lookarounds enough to know if they are applicable in this case. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store the mac-address to search in a variable and use Bash's replace expanded value to generate the Regex for `grep`:

```bash
mac='56:ea:b6:a6:82:5e'

# Compose a regex on-the fly by replacing all colons with [:.-]?
grep -iE "${mac//:/[:.-]?}"
```

Or same as a function:

```bash
grepmac() {
  # Usage:
  # grepmac MAC_ADDRESS FILE [FILE]...

  # Parses input argument 1 as mac-address
  # regardless if it uses delimiters or not.
  # Returns failure if input argument 1 is not a mac-address.
  [[ $1 =~ ([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2}) ]] || return 1

  # Sets delimiter locally to : to join matches with colon
  local -- IFS=:
  # Joins matches except first to get a colon-delimited mac-address
  mac="${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}"

  # Shifts out first argument away to only keep remaining file paths
  shift

  # Composes a regex by replacing colons in mac-address by [:.-]?
  # which matches optional delimiter with : . or - 
  regex=${mac//:/[:.-]?}

  # Performs the actual search
  grep -iE "$regex" "$@"
}
```

Traced execution of `grepmac`:

```
$ set -x; grepmac 56eab6a6825e

+ grepmac 56eab6a6825e
+ [[ 56eab6a6825e =~ ([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2})[:.-]?([[:xdigit:]]{2}) ]]
+ IFS=:
+ mac=56:ea:b6:a6:82:5e
+ shift
+ regex='56[:.-]?ea[:.-]?b6[:.-]?a6[:.-]?82[:.-]?5e'
+ grep --color=auto -iE '56[:.-]?ea[:.-]?b6[:.-]?a6[:.-]?82[:.-]?5e'
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It looks like it only finds the unseparated value.

Comment: Did you test it before asking if I did?

Comment: I like the simplicity of this one-liner. It works great although I don't understand the syntax of the expression. Does //:/ mean find all colons and replace them with what comes next? It seems like I need to include delimiters in the variable; it doesn't work if I'm searching for 56EAB6A6825E for example.

Comment: @cmdr_keen I added explanations and a similar but more optimized function inspired by what [John Kugelman wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73160452/7939871)

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation and updated function. Both work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that takes a MAC address—uppercase or lowercase, with or without punctuation—and constructs a regex from it. You can run it just like `grep`, with either a list of files or nothing to read from stdin.

```
grep-mac() {
    local mac="$1"
    local files=("${@:2}")

    # Strip punctuation from the input MAC.
    mac="${mac//[^[:alnum:]]}"
    # Create a regex by inserting `[:-\.]?` in between every two characters.
    local regex="${mac:0:2}$(sed -E 's/../[:-\\.]?\0/g' <<< "${mac:2}")"

    # Call `grep` with the regex and files we were passed.
    grep -iE "$regex" "${files[@]}"
}
```

Example usage:

```
❯ grep-mac 56:ea:b6:a6:82:5e syslog.log | less
❯ grep-mac 56EAB6A6825E syslog.log | less
```

You can put it in your `~/.bashrc` if you want easy access.

Comment: Great idea with creating a function. I use this frequently enough that I think this is the best solution for me. Although I do like the idea of using a variable like @LéaGris suggested below as that is more easily done on the fly. I will probably use both!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `grep`

```
$ grep -Ei '56[[:alnum:]:.-]+5e' <(less syslog.log)
```